# Do I need X + gnome?

Tags: solaris, x11, gnome

I'm trying to reduce the size of a few solaris installations I have. These are headless T1000 machines running solaris 10. Serving as oracle, apache and jboss servers,  is there really any reason to have X Windows and gnome installed? Am I likely to break anything if I remove these packages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to break anything, no.

Just make sure you leave the X client libraries on the system; various system configuration tools and application tools (read: Oracle installer) will use those.